# Is it functionally/ practically more efficient to create a CLI program that uses Console.Readline();, or args[i] for input?

Tags: c#, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

When creating a console based app, is it functionally more efficient/ practically more efficient to run off of command line start arguments than it is to use `Console.ReadLine();`? I have two options, open the program and have it listen to my commands via `ReadLine` in a console window, or I can use CMD like: `C:\MYPROGRAM argument` and have it take my commands this way. (think ping.exe for example)

I have used `string userCommand = Console.ReadLine();` along with `if` statements in order to control my program. I have also used `userCommand = args[x]` as a way to command my program from CMD.

Examples:

```
string userCommand = Console.ReadLine();
if(userCommand == "help")
{
Console.WriteLine(help);
}
```

Or

```
if(args[0] == "help")
{
Console.WriteLine(help);
}
```

Both of these methods are working for me, but I do not understand which of these is going to be more efficient in terms of speed/ performance. I also do not understand which one of these is practically a better solution. Is one of these superior to the other for any specific functional/ practical/ potential reason? Note: Google wasn't particularly helpful here.

Comment: Any performance differences between the two are likely more than offset by the time it takes a human to type.

Comment: Depending on what the application's purpose is, you probably want to support both. Command line arguments open the door to automation. If there are no command line arguments, you can fall back to prompting for user input.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I felt that it might be better to open that up so that others wouldn't need to redirect IO in order to automate my functions.

Comment: *loses rep points for not knowing answer to own question*

Answer (score 1):

The cost of creating a new process and initializing the CLR is several orders of magnitude larger than either of these.  So there is no practical difference in efficiency between them.